# Why am I not seeing the best regularization parameter value in the results?

Tags: python

I want to see the best value of C in the results. Why is the following code giving only the selectkbest value?

```
    steps = [('selectkbest', SelectKBest(f_classif)), ('LR', LogisticRegression())]

    pipeline = Pipeline(steps)

    k = [k+1 for k in range(len(X_train.columns))]
    param_grid = {'selectkbest__k': k}, {'LR__C':[.001,.01,.1,1,10,100]}

    cv = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid, cv=5, scoring='recall', n_jobs=-1)

    cv.fit(X_train, y_train)

    y_pred = cv.predict(X_val)

    y_predprob = cv.predict_proba(X_val)[:,1]

    print(classification_report(y_val, y_pred))
    print("Tuned Model Parameters: {}".format(cv.best_params_))
```

Comment: You should put an example that can be reproduce, for example in this code we cannot know what is ```Pipeline``` or ```GridSearchCV```

Comment: Thank you - will make sure to add the data in my future questions. I was able to solve this issue, turned out I had to remove the curly brackets between selectkbest and LR.